# dtrace on Windows: "in action list: failed to resolve nt`_GUID: Unknown symbol name"

Tags: windows, dtrace

I installed dtrace on Windows 10, with this version:

```
C:\Users\xyz>dtrace -V
dtrace: Sun D 1.13.1
```

This command does not work:

```
C:\Users\xyz>dtrace -n "tick-3sec { trace(sizeof(nt`_GUID));exit(0);} "
dtrace: invalid probe specifier tick-3sec { trace(sizeof(nt`_GUID));exit(0);} : in action list: failed to resolve nt`_GUID: Unknown symbol name
```

Same problem with a `struct _EPROCESS` : Any declaration of a `_EPROCESS` variable fails. I tried from CMD and PowerShell resulting to the same error message.

However, D scripts with pointers to a `struct _GUID` run fine, for example a cast: (struct nt`_GUID  *).

Idea, please ?